# Get list of pdf files in storage - Mediastore android

Tags: java, android, pdf, mobile, mediastore

Can someone help me with this issue, I am trting to get list of pdf files from external storage but the array always empty, this is my code:

Thank you in advance.

This is my code:

```
public static ArrayList<String> getPdfFiles(Context context) {
        ArrayList<String> listOfAllFiles = new ArrayList<>();

        Uri uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};
        // only pdf
        String selectionMimeType = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?";
        String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("pdf");
        String[] selectionArgsPdf = new String[]{ mimeType };
        Cursor allPdfFiles = cr.query(uri, projection, selectionMimeType, selectionArgsPdf, null);

        while (allPdfFiles.moveToNext()) {
            int nameIndex= allPdfFiles.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.TITLE);
            String name= allPdfFiles.getString(nameIndex);
            listOfAllFiles.add(name);
        }
        return listOfAllFiles;
    }
```

Comment: Please do not provide snapshots of the code. Provide the code you are trying as text.

Comment: Could you please add your code as text,,,

Comment: Hello @PawaraSiriwardhane,

I have updates my post.
Thanks

Comment: It is great. Thank you, too for correcting the post.

Comment: just to note that for android 10 _DATA column does not exist. It was reintroduced for android 11 though. Also why not just look for a .pdf extension eg from the _DATA column variable.endsWith(*.pdf"), a lot easier